# Small grinder for espresso

Tags: espresso, grinder

I am looking for a small grinder to grind espresso grade. Most of the good grinders out in the market are huge or mid-size. My kitchen is pretty small and I don't have space for yet another machine.

*Goal:* To find a grinder with the following properties:

- Minimal; Small; Something between 16oz - 20oz is ideal
- Can do fine grinding; Espresso grade
- Electric
- Easy to clean

*Problem:*

- Looks like most grinders that do fine grinding are mid-size up
- Small grinders do not specify grade properties (at least the ones I have seen)

*Question:*

- **What to look for in a small grinder to make sure it satisfies the
  properties mentioned above (most importantly fine grinding capability)**

Comment: I think product recommendations are off topic, there are plenty of manual grinders or small electric grinders you can purchase

Comment: maybe you can edit your question to ask what the features to look for and how size impacts those decisions.

Comment: See also previous questions over at Cooking.SE, before Coffee.SE existed: [grinders](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/3038/25286) and [hand crank](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/45261/25286). More by searching there. Meta: weigh in about [product recommendations here](http://meta.coffee.stackexchange.com/q/5/262). I don't see a [meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com) policy, so perhaps this is a per-site decision...?

Comment: @EdChum I can see your concern regarding product recommendations. But honestly, I am looking to see if someone had a similar problem and what the solution was. Yes I know there are plenty of small grinders in the market, but the question is if they are any good for expresso grade.

Comment: I have a ceramic burr grinder which is adjustable I see no reason why it can't grind coffee fine enough for espresso machines

Comment: Basically the variants are manual/electric blade type/burr type and then the material used for the grinding mechanism and the volume, it takes me about 2-3 mins to grind 22g of coffee beans, this is about double the normal amount for a single espresso

Comment: Sorry, yeah. We cannot open that door to allowing broad  "what is best..." product recommendations. It's just a poor fit for this type of Q&A. There are simply too many variables and the needs of one person doesn't necessarily meet the needs of another. Recommendations quickly devolve into a popularity contest, and users would only be guessing if they are helping you specifically. If you have any questions about these products or features themselves, it would be likely find to ask here, but asking folks which product to buy has to be off topic for this site. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: all that said, I think with edits there is a useful question here. I'll watch and vote to reopen if edited to fit the guidelines.

Comment: You may wish to ask a similar question over at [cooking.se] if the above links I posted are not satisfying. E.g., combine it with other needs: you want a multi-tasking device; e.g., for a small kitchen, you might want a device you could also use for grinding spices (e.g., peppercorns).

Comment: If you're *really* short on space (you say that you "don't have space for yet another machine"), the obvious solution also exists: have the beans ground for you at a coffee shop when you buy them, in batches small enough for you to drink them before going stale.

Comment: @RobertCartaino I modified the question to clarify the problem. Also the question is no more about product recommendation. Could you clarify how this question is not within the `coffee scope`? Can you also provide the link to the scope? I couldn't find it!